# Proving $ F_{m}F_{n}=\dfrac{1}{5}(L_{m+n}-(-1)^{n}L_{m-n}) $ for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: matrices, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

How can I prove the following identity about the Fibonacci numbers by using matrices or determinants?

$ F_{m}F_{n}=\dfrac{1}{5}(L_{m+n}-(-1)^{n}L_{m-n}) $

Comment: What is $L_m$ ?

Comment: @Rol, probably Lucas numbers.

Comment: Yes Lucas numbers

Comment: Are you looking specifically for solutions involving matrix / determinant? Or is any approach valid

Comment: I will accept any solution without using Binet's Formula. How can I prove this?