# I have this home work problem i cannot proved this sum over product of fibonacci sequence i used definition of fibonacci numbers and geometric sums

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

how to prove this fibonacci identity?
 $\sum_{k=0}^{n-3} F_k F_{n-k-3}$ = $(1/5)[ (n-3) L_{n-3} - F_{n-3}]$
I used generating functions and geometric sum and  how i could get the result.?

Comment: Why is it based on $n-3$?  It seems like it could be based on $n$ just as easily... is there some significance?

Comment: yes it is according to my thesis it was stated 0 to n-3 i need to derive the geometric sum? i change it to n-3? what should i do?

Comment: Since $$\sum_{h\geq 0}F_h x^h = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{1-\varphi x}-\frac{1}{1-\bar{\varphi}x}\right)$$
by squaring both sides and by applying partial fraction decomposition we immediately get:
$$ \sum_{h\geq 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{h}F_k F_{h-k}\right)x^h = \sum_{h\geq 0}\frac{hL_h-F_h}{5}\,x^h.$$
An equivalent, alternative derivation is just to exploit the explicit formulas for Fibonacci and Lucas numbers.

Comment: Thanks sir for the idea this is the same as in n-3 we just change our n to n-3 in every subscipt since it hold for all integer n?

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as
$\sum_{k=0}^{n} F_k F_{n-k}
=(1/5)[ nL_{n} - F_{n}]
$.

In the "Related" column
it points to this:
[Proving $ F_{m}F_{n}=\dfrac{1}{5}(L_{m+n}-(-1)^{n}L_{m-n}) $ for Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195377/proving-f-mf-n-dfrac15l-mn-1nl-m-n-for-fibonacci-numbe?rq=1)

If this is true
(there is no answer supplied,
but Binet's formula would probably
be useful),
the problem becomes

$\begin{array}\\
(1/5)[ nL_{n} - F_{n}]
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} F_k F_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{5}(L_{n}-(-1)^{n-k}L_{2k-n})
\qquad m \to k, n \to n-k\\
&=(n+1)L_n/5-\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{5}(-1)^{n-k}L_{2k-n}\\
\end{array}
$

or
$ L_{n} + F_{n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}L_{2k-n}
$
and this,
if true,
can probably be solved
by using Binet's formulas
for the
$F_n$ and $L_n$.

(added later)

Note:

Binet's formulas are,
where
$\phi
=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$,

$F_n
=\dfrac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}
$
and
$L_n
=\phi^n+(-\phi)^{-n}
$.

These might be useful.

Comment: sir can i transform the geometric series because its n-3  it becomes  $S_n$ = $ \sum_{k=0} ^{n-3} r^k  = r^{-3} - r^{n-2} / 1-r$ ? this is my transfored geometric series can i used this to answer my question?

Comment: No, because the sum is of $F_k F_{n-k}$. If you substitute Binet's formula, you get a number of geometric series which you can then sum.

Comment: sir i need to consider it from 1 to n? rather than 1 to n-3? since it is valid for all integer n? if this is true.

Comment: Just replace n-3 with n everywhere.

Comment: sir thanks a lot do you have a facebook account ? what is your name?